# c# When I export db data to excel file, file name was broken

Tags: c#, excel, character-encoding, export-to-excel

When I try to export DB data to excel file,

English file name is no problem, but when I try to set file name Korean

file name was broken.

But when I open exported excel file, it opens well and all texts are also okay.

How can I fix save file name code?

My code is below.

btnSaveClick Event

```
  protected void btnMemSaveExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //set Excel header as string[] ExcelHeaders

        try
        {
            //Get siteTitle to use Excel file name.
            string siteTitle = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb().Title;

            //some codes..
            ExcelExport(Page.Response, ds.Tables[0], siteTitle + "_MemberList", siteTitle + "_MemberList", ExcelHeader, true)
        }
    }
```

Excel Export

```
private static void ExcelExport(HttpResponse response, DataTable dataTable, string fileName, string sheetTitle, string[] colHeader, bool borderLine)
{
    ExcelWorkSheet ws = null;
    int rowNum = 1;

    if(dataTable != null && dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
        ws = pck.WorkBook.Worksheets.Add(sheetTitle);

        //set header, set data, etc

        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.xlsx", fileName));

        response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
        response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add your English file name and Korean file name?

Comment: Your code is missing few information for anyone to help you. For e.g fileName declaration and further assignments. post the complete code

Comment: If you can save the contents in English then you can save the file name in Korean using Encoding look at this link and just do the encoding and apply it to the filename https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621532/c-sharp-save-a-file-with-korean-encoding

Comment: Sorry to bothering you. I edited code. And I get file name from SharePoint site`s title. That site name is diffrent(English, Korean).

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem.

Added new line

```
string fileSaveName = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("fileName.TrimEnd());
```

And modify code

```
response.AddHeader("content-dispositon", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.xlsx", fileSaveName));
```